# SQL Query expensive calculation by date filters and column filter

Tags: java, sql, date

expens table contains four fields

```
(Date(Date),Breakfast(INT),Lunch(INT),Dinner(INT) Expense(INT))
```

I just need to filter date wise and column wise .

1. if i select date wise means i will get expense amount on that date
   Ex:breakfast+lunch+dinner(Int) on particular date
2. If want only breakfast means it must add (breakfast+breakfast)(INT) throught the particular month
   Ex:Feb expenses on breakfast

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might want to read, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you show a query You tried?

Comment: That's 5 columns, not 4...

Comment: Statements s1=c.createStatement();
String query=”SELECTS SUM (IF MONTHNAME (date)=”February”,Breakfast,0),(Breakfast+lunch+dinner) as total
FROM Expense_Traze
WHERE MONTHNAME (date) =”February” OR date=”2012-2-11”;
S1.execute(query);

Answer (score 0):

Statements s1=c.createStatement();

String query=”SELECTS SUM (IF MONTHNAME (date)=”February”,Breakfast,0),(Breakfast+lunch+dinner) as total
FROM Expense_Traze 
WHERE MONTHNAME (date) =”February” OR date=”2012-2-11”;

S1.execute(query);

---

Table Expense_Traze

Date(Date)  Breakfast(INT)  Lunch(INT)  Dinner(INT) Total(INT)

2016-2-11         10                  20           30         60

2016-2-11         30                  20           10         60

If it is the month of Feb means adds SUM (Breakfast) is 40 i e Column wise, if not means it will add (Breakfast+Lunch+Dinner) As Total on Particular date like 2016-3-15.

Comment: I don't Know whether it is right or wrong.Help Me Thanks in advance